# How setText in multiple TextView in onTick() method

Tags: android

I have small question.

```
new CountDownTimer(12000, 2000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}.start();
```

Here I would like `setText` to 6 different `TextView`(in one xml) with each `onTick()`. Any ideas how i can make this? Thanks

//edit

```
I would like have something like this     
First tick    
tv.setText("one")   
Second Tick   
tv2.setText("two")
```

Comment: try to use runonuithread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using Array of TextViews like

```
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[6];
String[] value = new String[]{"one","two","three","four","five","six"};
int count = 0;

new CountDownTimer(12000, 2000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        textViews[count].setText(value[count]);// you can set dynamic string variable also
                        count++; 
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }
                }.start();
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
new CountDownTimer(12000, 2000) {
    int counter = 0;

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        switch (counter) {
            case 0:
                tv1.setText("");
                break;
            case 1:
                tv2.setText("");
                break;

            // ...

        }
        counter++;
    }
    public void onFinish() {
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Answer,

```
   new CountDownTimer(12000, 2000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

               Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                     tv1.setText("");
                     tv2.setText("");
                     tv3.setText("");
                     tv4.setText("");

                  }
               });

          }
          public void onFinish() {

          }
   }.start();
```

Comment: I would like setText ONCE per tick. In each next tick i would like setText to other TextView. Any option?

Comment: take one int variable and increase it in onTick method and use switch or if for setting value in textview